# How to add leaflet Map into a power point document in R?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, powerpoint, reporters

I am using Reporters package to generate pptx document in a shiny app.

In [here](https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/reference/addImage.html#examples) there is some explanation of how to add external image to document by Reporters package. But I could not find a solution to import leaflet map to pptx via reporters. Any examples or information would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaflets are designed to be displayed in web pages (as htmlwidgets), this format is not supported by ReporteRs.

You can embed a screenshot of the leaflet (as an image) with webshot. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webshot/vignettes/intro.html